# Confusion implementing inverse z transform in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, z-transform

I am trying to use MATLAB commands ztrans and iztrans  , but i am not getting proper results
My code is below, why i am not getting H1=H2??Keeping in view that "H2" is "inverse Z transform" of "Z transform" of "H1"

```
clc
clear
syms z n
H1=(z.*(z-1))/((z+1)*(z+1/3))
pretty(H1);
f=iztrans(H1,n);
pretty(f)
H2=ztrans(f)
```

This outputs

[image: Output of matlab code.]

Comment: Please show your results

Comment: @DanBoschen Added a screenshot what I get for the output from Matlab. Just pasting the output formats it atrociously, so a screenshot was better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two answers are equivalent and related by partial fraction expansion.

This is clear when you multiplying out the numerator to get a common denominator:

$$
\begin{align}10z(z+1/5)& - 9z(z+1/3) \\&= 10z^2 + 2z - 9z^2 - 3z\\
&= z^2 - z\\
&= z(z-1)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The interesting thing is I get `H1 - H2 = (9*z)/(z + 1/5) - (10*z)/(z + 1/3) + (z*(z - 1))/((z + 1/3)*(z + 1/5))` and `simplify(H1-H2)` comes to 0. :-)

Comment: @PeterK.  Yes crazy when we subtract two identical things, we get zero, seems like a lot of work for nothing!

Comment: Yes! It's one reason why I don't believe that we'll reach AGI (artificial general intelligence) any time soon.